# ASP.NET MVC and Response.Write in a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in my ASP.NET MVC project master page:

```
    <%
    switch(Request.Browser.Browser) 
    {
        case "IE": // Internet Explorer
            Response.Write("<link href=\"./Content/Site_IE.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />");
            break;
        case "AppleMAC-Safari": // Chrome
            Response.Write("<link href=\"./Content/Site_FF.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />");
            break;
        case "Firefox": // Firefox
            Response.Write("<link href=\"./Content/Site_FF.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />");
            break;
        default: // All others
            Response.Write("<link href=\"./Content/Site_FF.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />");
            break;
    }
%>
```

When I embed directly with:

```
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

then it works, but when I embed with the switch statement, then it doesn't find the location from views, but it finds it on the start page.

How  can I map the path so it finds it from everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would rather see that decision made in the controller and the stylesheet passed in as a model property. You could test it easily and your markup would be a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
     <%       
 switch(Request.Browser.Browser) 
 {
     case "IE": %> // Internet Explorer 
         <link href="<%= Url.Content ("~/Content/Site_IE.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text"/css" />
         <% break;
     case "AppleMAC-Safari": %> // Chrome
         <link href="<%= Url.Content ("~/Content/Site_FF.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text"/css" />                
         <% break;
     case "Firefox": %> // Firefox
         <link href="<%= Url.Content ("~/Content/Site_FF.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text"/css" />                 
        <% break;
     default: %> // All others 
         <link href="<%= Url.Content ("~/Content/Site_FF.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text"/css" />
        <% break;
 } 
 %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this one:

```
Response.Write("<link href=\""+Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/Site_IE.css")+"\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />");
```

Answer (score 0):

"./" means "from the current directory".  Just use a path relative to the root of the application, starting with just a slash.

```
 Response.Write("<link href=\"/Content/Site_FF.css\"  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this was a pain at first.  [I wrote a blog post on how to get around this issue](http://www.stickfiguresoftware.com/node/46) and I even put up some code for helper methods you can swipe from my site.